# How to convert and store bitmapImages in Windows8

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I want to store bitmapimages on local directory. And I wrote those codes.but An unknown error occurred and can't compile.please tell me the cause of the error and the the right way to convert and store bitmapImages.

```
    void StoreAndGetBitmapImage()
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/" + "test.png"));
        StorageFile storageFile = ConvertBitmapImageIntoStorageFile(image, "image_name");
        StoreStorageFile(storageFile);
        BitmapImage resultImage = GetBitmapImage("image_name");
    }

    StorageFile ConvertBitmapImageIntoStorageFile(BitmapImage bitmapImage,string fileName)
    {
        StorageFile file = Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(bitmapImage.UriSource).GetResults();
        file.RenameAsync(fileName);
        return file;
    }

    void StoreStorageFile(StorageFile storageFile)
    {
        storageFile.CopyAsync(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
    }

    BitmapImage GetBitmapImage(string fileName)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapImage;
        bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(new Uri(
             Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\" +
             Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Name),
             fileName);

        return bitmapImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` asynchronous method calls. Therefore, you have to declare the method as async. For example:

```
async Task<StorageFile> ConvertBitmapImageIntoStorageFile(BitmapImage bitmapImage,string fileName)
{
    StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(bitmapImage.UriSource);
    await file.RenameAsync(fileName);
    return file;
}
```

`await` results in returning from the method. If the task is complete, the method is continued at this very position (maybe in a different thread). Asynchronous methods return an `IAsyncOperation` object, e.g. a `Task`. This is a handle to the started procedure and can be used to determine, when it is done.

Comment: Thanks Nico ! I do'nt use "await" Intentionally,because I want to run this method Synchronously.

Comment: Then you have to call `Wait()` on the return value of async operations.